# Can I just kill the process mysqld.exe for shutting down MySQL server in Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows

I know that we can shutdown MySQL server by executing the following:

```
/mysql/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=my.ini -u root -p shutdown
```

but the problem is it requires user input for entering the root password. The process of shutting down the MySQL server must not require user input.

So, can I just kill the process [mysqld.exe]?

Or is there any alternative better way?

Comment: if your password is "hello" then instead of -p write -phello

Comment: @HugoRegibo oh yeah... it works :)

Comment: @HugoRegibo you may consider repost as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your password is "hello" then instead of -p write -phello